# Can't enable Extbase and Fluid

Tags: typo3, fluid, extbase, typo3-6.2.x

I want to install Extbase and Fluid to create an extension for Typo3. I'm quite new to this CMS and still struggling with the installation of the two extensions. I've included a picture[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t9ZHx.png) which shows that there is no brick with a plus sign next to it. In every documentation or tutorial online, people can activate or deactivate the extension with that symbol.

The installation had no problems and everything else is working very good, so I don't quite understand what I'm doing wrong here? Maybe I have to enable some options I overlooked in the tutorial?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of TYPO3 6.0, `extbase` and `fluid` are mandatory extensions, they are installed by default and cannot be uninstalled. The reason is that some mandatory core extensions (especially the new extension manager which was introduced in 6.0) depend on them.

Comment: But Extbase is not visible in Admin Tools. (6.2.15). Can you give a hint on where to find it?

Comment: @Grrrben: In the extension manager, should be around the 16th extension from the top. At least it is in the example installation I have here.